# VB.Net 2005 Setup Project Application Data Folder no Content

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

Under VB.Net 2005, I created a Setup Project which produced installation files for a windows application. I placed the mdb file in the User's Application Data Folder and remapped the DataDirectory to Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData at runtime. Unfortunately, sometimes the system just did create the mdb file at the Application Directory. An example was that I installed the program in Windows 7 under a normal user account. I chose inside the installer that the program would be made available to everyone. After installation, the mdb file would be created automatically for the Administrator account but not for the normal user account. For XP, the whole thing worked fine.

I am tempted to write a routine to check and create the mdb file if it is not present, but why does this happens and what other opinions do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is installed for all users instead of once for each user that logs onto the machine, then you will eventually run into a problem where the database isn't available for the signed on user.

In order to resolve this, you would probably be better off checking for the existence of the database on application startup and then either copying a standard version from the application directory to the current user's data directory or creating a new db from scratch in place. I would recommend the first approach.

Comment: Thanks, I also added the condition to set and check the creation date of the file so that I can update the file when I deliver a newer version of the installer.

Comment: Excellent! Remember that if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the answer to let future visitors to the question know that this is what helped you solve your question.